# Does Dojo Toolkit provides CSS Column Grid Framework?

Tags: css, dojo, grid

Is there a CSS grid framework available in dojo, like 960gs or prototype grid system? I have searched but found none.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no CSS layout like that in dojo. There are dijit layout components that can help with layout but it's not a grid system.

Comment: thanks Jeremy. I have decided to use fluid 960 grid system - a liquid version of popular 960.gs.

Comment: You used 960 with Dojo?  Any public facing site I could see?